# Jersey SSE Client receives no events

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I'm trying to implement a Server-Sent-Events Client using Jersey 2.5.1 (can't upgrade to a later version), and the connection keeps getting closed, with no events being read.
I've reduced the code to what I believe is the simplest following possible from the [manual](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html), but without success.

I have tested my client against other servers, and the behaviour is the same, so I believe my problem is client based.
The client connects to the resource, and the server starts sending events. But no events are received, and the connection is closed prematurely.

I've also tried using EventSource instead of EventInput, but the results are the same.
Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Thanks.

Server Code:

```
@Path("events")
public class SseResource {

  /**
   * Create stream.
   * @return chunkedOutput of events.
   */
  @GET
  @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
    System.out.println("Received GetEvent");
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
            eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
            eventBuilder.data(String.class, "Hello world " + i + "!");
            final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
            eventOutput.write(event);
            System.out.println("Wrote event " + i);

            // ... code that waits 1 second
            try {
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Error when writing the event" + e);
          throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing the event.", e);
        } finally {
          try {
            eventOutput.close();
          } catch (IOException ioClose) {
            System.out.println("Error when closing the eventOuput" + ioClose);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
          }
        }
      }
    }).start();
    return eventOutput;
  }
}
```

Client Code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventInput;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.InboundEvent;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;
...
  public final void simpleClientTest() {
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    final WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8182/events");

    final EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
    while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
      final InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();
      if (inboundEvent == null) {
        // connection has been closed
        break;
      }
      System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; " + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
    }
    System.out.println("eventInput finished");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, finally, found the cause of the problem. The server-startup code (not given above) did not include the SseFeature.class resource. Including here in-case someone else has this issue....

```
  public void startServer() throws IOException {
    final URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0").port(serverPort).build();
    System.out.println("Starting media server at: " + baseUri);
    final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(SseResource.class, SseFeature.class);
    server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to write a simple Jersey SSE client for a Node.js based server. However, I am [not receiving any events on the client (click here for SO question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640962/jersey-sse-client-is-not-receiving-events). Any idea on what I could be missing?